# Plotting dot according conditions comparing three column, with facets

Tags: r

I've datas as follow

```
  datas=structure(list(RT_theorique = structure(c(18L, 28L, 36L, 42L, 
        50L, 5L, 13L, 23L, 33L, 40L, 46L, 37L, 43L, 47L), .Label = c("17:03:55", 
        "17:06:24", "17:08:53", "17:11:30", "17:13:57", "17:17:49", "17:25:01", 
        "17:34:49", "17:37:18", "17:41:10", "17:43:02", "17:45:27", "17:46:33", 
        "17:48:55", "17:51:09", "17:53:36", "17:56:45", "17:59:34", "18:03:13", 
        "18:05:52", "18:09:44", "18:11:49", "18:14:45", "18:18:01", "18:20:48", 
        "18:23:55", "18:26:47", "18:31:34", "18:34:42", "18:36:32", "18:38:32", 
        "18:41:57", "18:44:33", "18:47:57", "18:51:21", "18:59:16", "19:05:46", 
        "19:07:55", "19:11:24", "19:15:13", "19:25:35", "19:29:09", "19:33:02", 
        "19:36:08", "19:41:06", "19:44:31", "19:49:21", "19:53:43", "19:56:05", 
        "19:59:56"), class = "factor"), Result_theorique = c("E", "E", 
        "F", "F", "F", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "E", "E", "E"), 
            RT_real = structure(c(19L, 29L, 38L, 47L, 54L, 5L, 14L, 
            24L, 34L, 42L, 51L, 39L, 48L, 52L), .Label = c("17:03:13", 
            "17:05:44", "17:08:44", "17:11:39", "17:14:39", "17:18:06", 
            "17:21:13", "17:24:02", "17:27:05", "17:32:43", "17:35:59", 
            "17:38:40", "17:41:26", "17:44:43", "17:48:14", "17:51:14", 
            "17:55:00", "17:57:16", "18:00:12", "18:03:16", "18:06:03", 
            "18:09:59", "18:12:49", "18:15:37", "18:18:01", "18:21:31", 
            "18:26:09", "18:27:58", "18:29:52", "18:33:21", "18:36:40", 
            "18:38:50", "18:41:25", "18:44:35", "18:48:45", "18:52:08", 
            "18:54:19", "18:59:52", "19:02:28", "19:06:04", "19:11:18", 
            "19:15:03", "19:18:06", "19:21:37", "19:25:37", "19:28:26", 
            "19:30:22", "19:33:31", "19:36:16", "19:41:00", "19:45:15", 
            "19:52:00", "19:53:56", "19:59:58"), class = "factor"), Result_real = c("E", 
            "E", "F", "F", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "E", "E", 
            "E"), Experiment_code = structure(c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 
            10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("#N/A", 
            "Exp1", "Exp2", "Exp3", "Exp4", "Exp5", "Exp6", "Exp7", "Exp8", 
            "Exp9", "Exp10"), class = "factor"), Concordance = c("OUI", 
            "OUI", "OUI", "OUI", "NON", "NON", "OUI", "OUI", "OUI", "OUI", 
            "OUI", "OUI", "OUI", "OUI")), .Names = c("RT_theorique", 
        "Result_theorique", "RT_real", "Result_real", "Experiment_code", "Concordance"
        ), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
        29L, 21L, 22L, 23L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've experiments and there is `Result_theorique` that represent predicted result and `Result_real` and the real result of the experiment coded by `Experiment_code`. If `Result_theorique` is conform to `Result_real` the `concordance` will be `oui` else it will be `non`.

I want to have the following representation according two rules :

If `concordance` is `oui`I want to represent it by a blue Dot.
If `concordance` is `non` I Want to represent `Result_theorique` by a red dot and `Result_real` by a black dot.

in the X axis it will be `RT_theorique` (reaction time theorique)

[image]

I've tried the following code with facets for each `Experiment_code`

```
up_th  <- ggplot(datas, aes(RT_theorique,Result_real, fill=Concordance)) + geom_point() +facet_wrap("Experiment_code")+
   ggtitle("Mission par heure") +
   theme_bw() +
   theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16,lineheight=2, face="bold"),
   legend.text=element_text(size=12),
   legend.title=element_text(size=12, face="bold"),
   axis.text.y = element_text(size=12),
   axis.text.x = element_text(size=6, angle=45, hjust=1, vjust=1),
   strip.background = element_rect(fill = "White"))
```

I don't know how to specify dot's color ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
ggplot(datas, aes(RT_theorique,Result_real, col=Concordance)) + 
  geom_point(size=5) +
  facet_wrap("Experiment_code")+
  ggtitle("Mission par heure") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('black', 'blue')) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16,lineheight=2, face="bold"),
        legend.text=element_text(size=12),
        legend.title=element_text(size=12, face="bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=12),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=6, angle=45, hjust=1, vjust=1),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "White"))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(datas, aes(RT_theorique,Result_theorique, col=Concordance)) + 
  geom_point(size=5) +facet_wrap("Experiment_code")+
  ggtitle("Mission par heure") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('red', 'blue')) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16,lineheight=2, face="bold"),
        legend.text=element_text(size=12),
        legend.title=element_text(size=12, face="bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=12),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=6, angle=45, hjust=1, vjust=1),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "White"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the aim is in fact passing from the concordance representation to this conditional representation. if concordant then black dot in the result that would be the same in theory and realily. And if not concordant is to indicate the real result by a black dot and the theoritical by a red one, so two dot at the same time for the same experiment.